# php explode with possibility to escape delimiter

Tags: php, string

I got a string:

```
this,is,a","b,test
```

I want to explode it on comma's except for comma's that are wrapped in double quotes, these should be left unharmed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
preg_split('/(?<!"),(?!")/', $string)
```

This code uses Regular Expressions with a negative lookahead and lookbehind. You can test the Regex with http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm.

Answer (score 4):

While the regex posted by Adrian Lang should do you nicely (I can't do better), are you possibly looking for the [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) or [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) functions?

Comment: str_getcsv definitely does this without adding complexity and having to figure out a regex pattern