# PHP split comma-separated values but retain quotes

Tags: php, regex, string, csv, split

I'm trying to split a string that contains comma-separated set of values. This can be achieved simply by using `str_getcsv` but I have an additional requirement where it falls short of. I need to retain quotes.

With an input string of:

```
string(30) "Hello, "San Diego, California""
```

I tried two approaches:

#### explode

```
$result = explode(",", $string);
```

Which results in

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  [1]=>
  string(11) " "San Diego"
  [2]=>
  string(12) " California""
}
```

#### str_getcsv

```
$result = str_getcsv($string, ",");
```

This one results in

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  [1]=>
  string(21) "San Diego, California"
}
```

---

I prefer using `str_getcsv` because it splits the values properly but it trims the enclosing quotes out. I need those quotes so I'm hoping I could call the function without it automatically removing the quotes.

#### Additional Info

I am actually open for a regex solution but I am clueless in that area.

---

I tried the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158780/php-explode-with-possibility-to-escape-delimiter) and it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php explode with possibility to escape delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158780/php-explode-with-possibility-to-escape-delimiter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pushed the limits of my regex knowledge, and I was unable to come up with an elegant regex which covers all possible cases for the input string (e.g. If the string ends with a comma) without leaving empty matches at the end.

```
$parts = preg_split('/(?:"[^"]*"|)\K\s*(,\s*|$)/', $string);
```

By itself, this gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => "San Diego, California"
    [2] => 
)
```

And you can clean up the empty elements like this:

```
$result = array_filter($parts, function ($value) {
    return ($value !== '');
});
```

*Note: The regex trims white-space from the start/end of each match. Remove the `\s*` parts if you don't want that.*

Comment: I'm currently using a similar pattern I found in SO: `~(?:\'[^\']*\'|"[^"]*"|)\K(,|$)~` but I don't really know what it does but somehow it works. What's the difference between what I found and your pattern? Also I'm fine with empty elements as I'm doing `array_filter` so they would be removed afterwards.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio It's basically the same, except your one checks for single and double quotes, and my one only does double quotes but also trims white-space to give you results like `str_getcsv()` would.

Answer (score 0):

```
$wrapped = array_map(function($value) { 
   return "\"$value\"";
}, str_getcsv($string, ","));
```

**UPDATE:** You could try something like this:

```
$value = preg_split('~(?:\'[^\']*\'|"[^"]*"|)\K(,|$)~', $string);
```

I lifted this from [PHP get comma separated values which are not enclosed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460967/php-get-comma-separated-values-which-are-not-enclosed?rq=1)

Comment: This will wrap all elements with quotes. I only want quotes on elements that originally had quotes in them.

Comment: This answer might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460967/php-get-comma-separated-values-which-are-not-enclosed?rq=1